# Ошибка Command 'clear' returned non-zero (PyCharm) при запуске console-menu

Tags: python, pycharm, настройка

Ошибка при выводе меню из библиотеки console-menu 0.6.0 в PyCharm
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'clear' returned non-zero exit status 1.

python, библиотека [console-menu 0.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/)
В интерпритаторе, меню выводится нормально, в PyCharm ошибка.
Должна быть настройка в PyCharm в environment variables (была, слетела, найти не могу)

ps Так и не понял, как вставить код для примера. Коды выше по ссылке на console-menu 0.6.0

Answer (score 0):

настройка в PyCharm в environment variables

PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;TERM=xterm-color

решила проблему